# Where do "fiends" get their abnormal strength?

Tags: from-the-new-world

"Fiends" have tremendous killing potential, because they actively try to kill humans who cannot retaliate due to psychological and genetic safeguards against violence.

However, I have not seen anything that indicates that they have a particularly powerful Cantus. Is their ability not the same as that of a regular human?

I am raising this doubt, because

> Maria and Mamoru's daughter could defeat the strongest Cantus user in the village at such a young age.

Did I perhaps miss some information that indicates that Fiends are much stronger for some reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's actually two parts to your question:

> Do Akkis (fiends/ogres) have abnormal strength?

There's a bit of a disconnect here. Maria and Mamoru's child is not actually an Akki as mentioned in the last episode. The akki "K" in the flashback is actually a grown up teenager. So he could very well be that strong in the first place.

So the real question is: "Why is Maria and Mamoru's child so strong?"

This assertion does seem to be true since the kid is able to do precision kills while normal children of the same age have trouble levitating a ball.

A speculative answer would be to go back to the fact that Cantus is a power of the imagination. It's possible that Maria and Mamoru's child, having grown up outside the village and influence of humans, has a completely different mindset and thus different imaginative potential.

> Why was Maria and Mamoru's child able to defeat Shisei Kaburagi (the strongest Cantus user) at such a young age?

This is simply because Shisei, a normal human Cantus user, is restricted by attack inhibition.

So regardless of how powerful he is, he cannot hurt the child. On the other hand, the child can freely attack Shisei. Note Shisei does attempt to defend himself since he manages to protect himself against the rocks that the child threw at him. But once the child used his/her Cantus directly on Shisei, Shisei was as good as dead.

*In other words, if you tied a 200 pound wrestler against a wall and let a 10-year-old kick him in the balls repeatedly, eventually the kid is gonna win.*

Comment: ah yes, I apologize for inadvertently mixing two questions together, but I will not split them up because both have been answered.

Comment: Nah it's fine. Multi-part questions are welcome network wide.

Comment: Isn't it odd how Shinsei couldn't block the direct Cantus attack? Although he can't attack, he should be pretty good at defending, I guess.

Comment: @Omega Not when Cantus is used directly on his body. Which the kid doesn't take too long to realize. So the kid uses Cantus to bend Shinsei's body backwards and break it.

Comment: There is a difference between hurting and restraining though. I very well believe that the dude could have restrained the girl, but the dumb@#$ didn't. He (and everybody else) was either dumb or weak, or both. And if weaker than the girl, then that Yakomaru surely is a lucky son of a bitch for getting the right baby on the first time.